# Error carousel Uncaught TypeError... is not a function

Tags: wordpress, typeerror, carousel, bridge

after updating the Bridge Theme i noticed that the Bootstrap carousel.js v3.0.0 is not working anymore and causes an error.

i was wondering why Bridge or bootstrap is working with an old version like this. Also on apple devices the page looks shot to pieces.
Link: https://centro-italia.de

This is the error message:

Uncaught TypeError: $active.one(...).emulateTransitionEnd is not a function

timer https://centro-italia.de/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/plugins/bootstrap.carousel.js:149

---

maybe someone got an idea?!
thanks in advance...

Marcel

- i tried to update the bootstrap.carousel.js but i cant find a file...
- i renamed the file but causes more errors
- updated all plugins and theme
- disabled the last updated plugins to see if they are responsable
- went back in theme backups, but doesnt helps